# Online Jeopardy

Tags: web-apps, game

I have a DNN site. Instead of using one of the simplistic trivia/quiz modules that are out there, I would like to have an online Jeopardy game for visitors to my site. Much like the TV game, I would like to be able to setup my own categories and answers/questions, have daily doubles, and perhaps even have video tiles. It should be timed, and you should have two virtual opponents. At the end of the game, the results should be recorded for a top winners page.

Is there ANYTHING out there like this? I don't mind spending a couple hundred dollars for a good product. Even if its not a DNN module, that's fine too. I could run it as separate web application and place it in an iframe or new window or something.